# Why declare an instance as a supertype but instantiate it as a subtype, plus Liskov Substitution Principle

Tags: inheritance, solid-principles, oop, liskov-substitution-principle

I've been trying to understand the Liskov Substitution Principle for a couple of days now, and while doing some code tests with the very typical Rectangle/Square example, I created the code below, and came up with 2 questions about it.

**Question 1: If we have a superclass/subclass relationship, why would we want to declare an instance as the supertype but instantiate it (new it up) as the subtype?**

I understand why, if we're doing polymorphism through interfaces, we would want to declare and instantiate variables this way:

```
IAnimal dog = new Dog();
```

However, now that I recall about it in old programming classes and some blog examples, when using polymorphism through inheritance, i'd still see some examples where some code would declare a variable this way

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
```

In my code below, Square inherits from Rectangle, so when I create a new Square instance this way:

```
Square sq = new Square();
```

it still can be treated as a Rectangle, or added to a generic List of Rectangles, so why would someone want to still declare it as Rectangle = new Square() ? Is there a benefit I'm not seeing, or a scenario where this would be required? Like I said, my code below works just fine.

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle(300, 150);
        var sq = new Square(100);
        Rectangle liskov = new Square(50);

        var list = new List<Rectangle> {rect, sq, liskov};

        foreach(Rectangle r in list)
        {
            r.SetWidth(90);
            r.SetHeight(80);

            r.PrintSize();
            r.PrintMyType();

            Console.WriteLine("-----");
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Rectangle
    {
        protected int _width;
        protected int _height;

        public Rectangle(int width, int height)
        {
            _width = width;
            _height = height;
        }

        public void PrintMyType()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.GetType());
        }

        public void PrintSize()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Width: {0}, Height: {1}", _width, _height));
        }

        public virtual void SetWidth(int value)
        {
            _width = value;
        }

        public virtual void SetHeight(int value)
        {
            _height = value;
        }

        public int Width { get { return _width; } }
        public int Height { get { return _height; } }
    }

    public class Square : Rectangle
    {
        public Square(int size) : base(size, size) {}

        public override void SetWidth(int value)
        {
            base.SetWidth(value);
            base.SetHeight(value);
        }

        public override void SetHeight(int value)
        {
            base.SetHeight(value);
            base.SetWidth(value);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Even though this *should* be breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle, I get the following output:

"Width: 90, Height: 80

### ConsoleApp.Program+Rectangle

Width: 80, Height: 80

### ConsoleApp.Program+Square

Width: 80, Height: 80
ConsoleApp.Program+Square

**Question 2: So, why or how would this code sample be breaking the LSP? Is it only because of the Square invariant of all sides being equal breaks the Rectangle invariant that sides can be modified independently? If that's the reason, then the LSP violation would be theoretical only? Or how, in code, could I see this code breaking the principle?**

**Edit: Came up with a third question which came up in one of the LSP blog articles I was reading, and there was no answer so it's this**

**Question 3:** The Open-Closed principle states that we should introduce new behavior/functionality through new classes (inheritance or interfaces). So if for example, I have a WriteLog method in the base class, which has no preconditions, but I introduce a new subclass which overrides the method but ONLY actually writes to the log if the event is highly critical....if this is new intended functionality (precondition being hardened on the subtype), would that still be breaking the LSP? The two principles would appear to contradict one another in this case.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The Rectangle-Square problem is *the* typical violation of LSP...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Clarification...my code wasn't breaking the LSP at all. Reason is i didn't read the LSP paper from R. Martin carefully. The way it would have broken it is if the SetHeight and SetWidth methods were not declared as virtual in the first place. Because in my question they were virtual since the beginning, there was no problem about the LSP at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1: If we have a superclass/subclass relationship, why would we want to declare an instance as the supertype but instantiate it (new it up) as the subtype?

The reasons you would do this with a supertype are the same reasons you would do for with an interface.  All the reasons you list for why declaring the variable as its specific subtype rather than the supertype apply equally as well for why declaring the variable as its specific subtype rather than an interface that the subtype implements.

```
abstract class Car { ... }
public abstract class ToyotaCamery2011 extends Car ( ... )

class Garage {
    private Car car = new ToyotaCamery2011();
    public Car getCar() { return car; }
    ....
}

class Garage {
    private ToyotaCamery2011 toyotaCamery2011 = new ToyotaCamery2011();
    public Car getCar() { return toyotaCamery2011; }
    ....
}
```

As long as all the methods of `Garage` only use methods of `Car`, and the public interface of `Garage` only shows `Car` and nothing specific to `Prius2011`, the 2 classes are effectively equivalent. Which is more readily understandable, e.g. which one models the real world more closely? Which ensures I don't accidentally use a Prius-specific method, i.e. built a Prius-specific garage?  Which is just the slightest bit more maintainable when if I decide to get a new car?  Is the code improved in any way using the specific subtype?

---

> Question 2: So, why or how would this code sample be breaking the LSP? Is it only because of the Square invariant of all sides being equal breaks the Rectangle invariant that sides can be modified independently? If that's the reason, then the LSP violation would be theoretical only? Or how, in code, could I see this code breaking the principle?

Its difficult to talk about LSP without talking about promises/contracts.  But Yes, if `Rectangle` promises that sides can be modified independently (more formally, if a postcondition for calling `Rectangle.setWidth()` includes that Rectangle.getHeight() should be unaffected), then `Square` deriving from `Rectangle` breaks LSP.

Your program does not depend on this property, so its fine. However take a program that is trying to satisfy a perimeter value or area value. Such a program may rely on the idea that `Rectangle` has independent sides.

Any class that accepts a `Rectangle` as input and depends on this property/behavior of `Rectangle` will likely break when given a `Square` as input. Programs like this can either jump through hoops to look for and disallow a `Square` (which is knowledge of a subclass) or it can change the contract of `Rectangle` with respect to independent sizes.  Then all the programs that use `Rectangle` can check after every call to `setWidth()` or setLength()`to see whether the adjacent side also changed and react accordingly. If it does the latter, than`Square`deriving frmo`Rectangle` is no longer a violation of LSP.

Its not just theoretical, it can have real impact on software, but it is often compromised upon in practice.  You see this in Java often unfortunately.  Java's `Iterator` class provides a `remove()` method that is optional.  Classes that use iterator must have knowledge about the implementing class and/or its subclasses to know whether its safe to use `Iterator.remove()`.  This violates LSP, but its accepted practice in Java. It makes writing and maintaining software more complex and more susceptible to bugs.

---

> Question 3: The Open-Closed principle states that we should introduce new behavior/functionality through new classes (inheritance or interfaces). So if for example, I have a WriteLog method in the base class, which has no preconditions, but I introduce a new subclass which overrides the method but ONLY actually writes to the log if the event is highly critical....if this is new intended functionality (precondition being hardened on the subtype), would that still be breaking the LSP? The two principles would appear to contradict one another in this case.

I think you mean postconditions when you say preconditions - you're describing about the what the method promises to fulfill.  If so, then I see no LSP violation - if the method superclass promises nothing, then the subclass can do what it likes and still be perfectly substitutable.  The fact that the subclass is more selective ("ONLY actually writes") about what it writes is new functionality, especially in light of the fact that the superclass promises nothing.

Comment: Hi Bert, thanks for your response..just couple of questions about your reply:

1. I still feel that making the declaration that way is different between Interfaces and Derived Classes, because if you declare an instance as the interface and new it up as the subtype, you will only see the methods/properties that appear on the interface definition, and not any extra methods/properties that the subtype might have. On the other side if you do the declaration as the base class and  new it up as the subtype, you'd see both the inherited methods and the subclass specific ones. No?

Comment: Actually, my mind just opened up. If we were using factory methods to determine the subtype instead of new'ing it up directly, it'd make sense to declare as the base type. OK. that takes care of Question 1.

Comment: About your response to question 2, Yes, the "logical" or "semantic" invariant of one shape breaks the other shapes invariant, but that is only logically. What i want to know is if, given my first code (which does work as expected for all three scenarios that i could think: declaring a Rectangle, a Square, and a Rectangle and new'ing it up as square), is there a scenario that i'm missing that would actually create code-specific un-expected behavior? Or would it be only a theoretical break of the principle?

Comment: For Question 3, Bert, I did mean preconditions. I mean, I've read the example that if a base class method allows any integer to be processed in a method, any subtype must NOT harden the condition to only process positive integers, which is what i meant when i used the example of event criticality. If i'm only accomplishing the business method action (coming from it's name, Write To Log) depending on a property of the parameter that is not checked on the original method in the super class, would I be breaking LSP?

Comment: @silverCore - Question 2 - Agreed its only a theoretical issue.  Since your program does not rely on the "independent sides" property of Rectangle, then the fact that Square violates this property is of no consequence to your program. Its only of consequence to a program that relies on that property of Rectangle.

Comment: @silverCode - Q3 - I agree for LSP that a subclass method can loosen the superclass method's preconditions (domain of inputs of the subclass can be larger) and it can tighten the superclass method's postconditions (the domain of outputs can be smaller). I agree that your integer example in your comment is talking about preconditions: you talk about what your method will accept, not what it will do..

Comment: @silverCode - Q3 - But the log example in the question is talking about what a method will do, not what it accepts - postcondition. If the superclass promises every event will be output to log, then the subclass violates LSP.  If the superclass log promises to accept any event but does not promise it will be written out, then the subclass doesn't violate the postcondition.

Comment: @silverCode - BTW "if you do the declaration as the base class and new it up as the subtype, you'd see both the inherited methods and the subclass specific ones." Yes and no, you get the subclass implementation of any methods it overrides, but you do not any new methods of the subclass that are not defined in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that this should break the Liskov Substitution Principle?

What the LSP is really about is that methods should Do The Right Thing if they are passed objects that are of a subtype rather than the original type.  Meaning that if you can prove that the method "does the right thing" if you pass it objects of the type, then it will "do the right thing" if you replace those objects with objects of a subtype.

But in your case you have no method calls, and so the LSP is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: btilly, what do you mean i have no method calls? What about the calls to SetHeight and SetWidth in the loop?

Comment: also, about hardening preconditions, the subclassed WriteToLog method would "harden" the requirements to do the actual write to the log file, depending on the event (assume its a parameter) criticality. On the Wikipedia page, doing that is considered breaking LSP, isn't it?